# Forces equal and opposite in elastic collision with different masses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

I just learned about conservation of momentum in my mechanics class.

So say we have two objects, one moving towards another at rest.

I know that in an elastic collision with identical masses, the one that is moving will be at rest after the collision. If I'm getting it right, this is because in the instant they hit, the moving object applies a force to the one at rest. Then an equal and opposite force is given back (because of Newton's third law and elastic collisions), canceling out the pushing force it had. So it is at rest.

Now say the resting object has more mass than the moving one. If the above reasoning is true, then shouldn't the the moving one still be given back an equal and opposite force by Newton's third law during the collision, causing it to be at rest after the collision?

But the conservation of momentum equation tells me it has to bounce back.

Where am I misunderstanding this?

Thanks

Comment: Forces in a Newton third law pair can't cancel each other because they acts on a different bodies.

Comment: Just because the force is equal and opposite doesn't mean that it will be such that it brings the first object to rest.

Answer (score 1):

> > If I'm getting it right, this is because in the instant they hit, the
> > moving object applies a force to the one at rest. Then an equal and
> > opposite force is given back (because of Newton's third law and
> > elastic collisions), canceling out the pushing force it had. So it is
> > at rest.

That’s not the reason the moving object comes to rest. As you are already aware, the forces are equal and opposite for the unequal masses also, but the moving object doesn’t come to rest when the masses are unequal. You need to keep in mind the equal and opposite forces per Newton's third law act on different objects so they do not "cancel”.

The final velocity of each mass following the elastic collision is determined by simultaneously solving the equations for conservation of momentum and kinetic energy. See the following for a head on collision: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol2.html#c1. For a head on collision between a moving and stationary object of the same mass the solution dictates that the moving object comes to a stop. Keep in mind that, at the macroscopic level, there are no perfectly elastic collisions.

The magnitude of the equal and opposite forces in each elastic collision depends on the rate of change in momentum. Newton's 3rd law dictates that the rate of change in momentum of each object is equal and opposite to that of the other. The duration of the collision will depend on the “springiness” of the objects, a material property.  See the following animation for collisions between objects attached to springs where you can simulate ideal and damping (inelastic) behavior. https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/collide-spring-en.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nice doubt!

Suppose that there is a really heavy block and you throw a small tennis ball towards it. It will seem that the tennis ball should bounce back with nearly the same speed as it was thrown. But why will the moving object not stop instead?

You are right that there will be equal and opposite force, but **the magnitude of force actually depends on the masses of the bodies.** If you run into someone your weight, you will feel less pain than if you run into someone heavier than you(just an analogy to help you understand :D)

$\int Fdt$ is the impulse (change in momentum), where F is the instantaneous force during collision.
For the heavier stationary body case, The magnitude of Force will be higher and therefore the ball will not just stop, but also rebound.

So how do we decide what the velocity of the colliding bodies will be after collision? **The answer lies in energy conservation.**

You need two equations to solve for 2 variables (final velocities of both bodies are the 2 variables).

*If you solve the energy conservation and momentum conservation equations, you will get the relative velocity of approach(before collsion) is equal to relative velocity of separation(after collision) in an elastic collision.* Now we use the above statement:

If the moving body(lighter) comes to rest, the heavier body will move, but at a slower speed(to conserve momentum). So the velocity of separation will be less than velocity of approach, which means it was an partially inelastic collision.

I think you will learn the derivation of V(separation)=V(approach) later in after energy is introduced. You can try deriving it by conserving kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2}mv^2$). If you need the derivation, I happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

*If I'm getting it right, this is because in the instant they hit, the moving object applies a force to the one at rest. Then an equal and opposite force is given back (because of Newton's third law and elastic collisions), canceling out the pushing force it had. So it is at rest* is **incorrect**.

*the moving object applies a force to the one at **rest***, $\vec F_{\text{on rest due to moving}}$, is **correct**.

*Then an equal and opposite force is given back* is incorrect because the equal and opposite force due to the object at rest acts on the object that is **moving**, $\vec F_{\text{on moving due to rest}}$.

Thus, $\vec F_{\text{on rest due to moving}} = - \vec F_{\text{on moving due to rest}}$ and then the change in momentum of the two objects is of the same magnitude but opposite in direction.

$\displaystyle \int^{\rm finish}_{\rm start}\vec F_{\text{on rest due to moving}} \,dt=-\int^{\rm finish}_{\rm start}\vec F_{\text{on moving due to rest}} \,dt$

This gives you the conservation of linear momentum equation and the fact that the collision is elastic gives you the conservation of kinetic energy equation.

Note that no mention of the relative masses of the objects has been made.
It so happens that when the two objects have the same mass all the momentum from the mass which was initially moving is transferred to the mass that was initially at rest.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to demonstrate that the forces between the two are equal and opposite even when the initial moving object does not come to rest, using the impulse concept.

An impulse is a force that exerted for a short period $dt$. Force can be expressed as $$F = ma = m \ dv/dt = dP/dt.$$

If the elastic collision occurs over a short period $dt$ then the force exerted by the m on M is $$F_m = m (u_i-u_f)/dt$$  and the reaction force exerted by M on m is $$F_M = M(V_i - V_f)/dt,$$ where $V_i$ and $V_f$ are the initial and final velocities of M.

From conservation of momentum we have the relation $$m u_i + MV_i = m u_f +MV_f$$

$$\implies \quad  m = M \frac{(V_f - V_i)}{(u_i - u_f)}$$

If we substitute this expression for m in terms of M into the expression for $F_m$ we get:

$$F_m = M (V_f - V_i)/dt$$

and this is clearly equal in magnitude and opposite in sign, to the expression we obtained for $F_M$ above. Note, there is no assumption that $u_f =0$ in obtaining the above result.

Some of the above equations have been simplified and abbreviated by using the assumption that $V_i = 0$. The full equations can be found at  [LibraTexts Physics](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Mechanics_and_Relativity_(Idema)/04%3A_Momentum/4.07%3A_Totally_Elastic_Collisions).